# How is this inheritance working in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Watching a React course, he wanted to extract a Component into a more reusable component, My question/confusion is about this line below:
`this.doSubmit();` that how does it even not error? because `doSubmit()` is in the **CHILD** class. It is not defined in the **parent** class. So shouldn't it error?

```
class Form extends Component {
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // bunch of code then next line is my question: 

    this.doSubmit();
  };
}

class LoginForm extends Form {
  doSubmit = () => {
    // call server
    console.log("submitted");
  };
}
```

Comment: It's because `this` will be an _instance_ of the LoginForm, which will have methods from both. This is also probably a poor design.

Comment: As long as  `handleSubmit()` is always called on a `LoginForm` instance, never on a `new Form()`, it'll work. But yes, this is a bad practice - `doSubmit` should at least have been declared/documented as an abstract method.

Comment: yeah looks like he is always calling it on the LoginForm instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned this is a course, I suspect there might be something more. But based on what you provided, this will not work: exactly as you said, the method is in child class.
I created a sample and you will see the error when call handleSubmit(): https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-buck-zpgll?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I was about to question all I knew about programming when I saw him doing it that way but yeah looks like he is for the purpose of the course is just always doing the actual button click call in the child form that has the handleSubmit method so it works but yeah won't work if directly called inside parent class.